# Using fby for cumulative sum in KDB/Q, but not getting the right output

Tags: sum, kdb, cumulative-sum

I am trying to use the fby function to create a new column that cumulatively sums a Volume column by a Symbol.

I have a table named x that looks like this:

| Timestamp | Symbol | VOL | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | A | 2 | 10 |
| Cell 2 | A | 5 | 20 |
| Cell 3 | A | 2 | 10 |
| Cell 4 | B | 3 | 20 |
| Cell 5 | B | 6 | 10 |
| Cell 6 | B | 1 | 20 |

I tried the following fby function to do so, but it just spits out the same as the "VOL" column:

```
x: update cumSum: sums (deltas;VOL) fby Symbol from x
```

`x`

| Timestamp | Symbol | VOL | Price | cumSumVOL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | A | 2 | 10 | 2 |
| Cell 2 | A | 5 | 20 | 5 |
| Cell 3 | A | 2 | 10 | 2 |
| Cell 4 | B | 3 | 20 | 3 |
| Cell 5 | B | 6 | 10 | 6 |
| Cell 6 | B | 1 | 20 | 1 |

However, this is what I am expecting the following:

| Timestamp | Symbol | VOL | Price | cumSumVOL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | A | 2 | 10 | 2 |
| Cell 2 | A | 5 | 20 | 7 |
| Cell 3 | A | 2 | 10 | 9 |
| Cell 4 | B | 3 | 20 | 3 |
| Cell 5 | B | 6 | 10 | 9 |
| Cell 6 | B | 1 | 20 | 10 |

Please let me know if you know where I'm making a mistake or have some advice, appreciate the help.

Comment: Alternatively, if there is a way to get a separate table with the Symbol name and the sum of VOL that could be a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deltas` isn't needed in your above example - below will accomplish what you're looking to do

```
q)show x:([]Timestamp:"Cell ",/:"123456";Symbol:`A`A`A`B`B`B;VOL:2 5 2 3 6 1;Price:6#10 20)
Timestamp Symbol VOL Price
--------------------------
"Cell 1"  A      2   10
"Cell 2"  A      5   20
"Cell 3"  A      2   10
"Cell 4"  B      3   20
"Cell 5"  B      6   10
"Cell 6"  B      1   20
q)update cumSumVOL:(sums;VOL)fby Symbol from x
Timestamp Symbol VOL Price cumSumVOL
------------------------------------
"Cell 1"  A      2   10    2
"Cell 2"  A      5   20    7
"Cell 3"  A      2   10    9
"Cell 4"  B      3   20    3
"Cell 5"  B      6   10    9
"Cell 6"  B      1   20    10
```

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I should have had sums where I had deltas previously.

Comment: You don't need to use `fby` either, a simple `by` would do it. e.g. `update cumSum:sums VOL by Symbol from x`